# How can I have a disabled button in a btn-group after a call to reset?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have a `disabled button` in a `btn-group` after a call to `reset`?

I have a `btn-group`. I set one `button` as `disabled`. All works fine.

But, if I call `button('reset')` then it removed the disabled on the button and it can NEVER be added again.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ejW3w/66/

```
$(".btn-group button").button("reset"); // removed the disable !!
$(".btn-group button").addClass('disabled').attr('disabled','disabled'); // This addclass does not re-add the disabled !!
```

I try add disabled with `.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled','disabled')` : but nothing works.

Thx..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".btn-group button").addClass('disabled').prop('disabled',true);
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/ejW3w/70/

Docs http://api.jquery.com/prop/